# What causes my app to break in strict mode after upgrading to react v18?

Tags: reactjs

I upgraded my app to react **v18** and replaced `ReactDOM` with `createRoot()` [as per the docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis), and I notice render issues:

In **v17**, my `<Restricted/>` component was rendering twice, once before fetching user data with a`useEffect()` in `App.js`, and once when the redux state is updated with the new user data.

But in react **v18** with **StrictMode** enabled, it only renders once.
Is there an issue with my implementation?

##### `App.js`

```js
function App() {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;
        
        if(isSubscribed) {
            // Fetching data
            // Dispatching to redux
        }
        return () => { isSubscribed = false }
    }, [dispatch, gettingUserInfo]);
    
    const Restricted = ({ routeType }) => {
        const cartSelection = location.state?.cartSelection;
        const isLogged = () => {
          console.log('# loggedIn :', loggedIn)
          return loggedIn;
        }
        if(loggedIn !== null) {
          if(routeType === "guest") {
            if(isLogged()){
              if(location.state?.from) {
                return <Navigate 
                  replace 
                  to={location.state.from}
                  state={{cartSelection: cartSelection}}
                />
              } else {
                return <Navigate replace to="/" />
              }
            } else {
              return <Outlet />;
            }
          } else if(routeType === "user") {
            return isLogged() ? (
              <Outlet /> 
            ) : <Navigate replace to="/" />;
          }
        } else {
          return <h2>Loading user data...</h2>
        }
    }

return (
    <>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
            ...
            {/* RESTRICTED - USER */}
            <Route element={<Restricted routeType="user" />}>
              <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile/>} />
            </Route>
            {/* RESTRICTED - GUEST */}
            <Route element={<Restricted routeType="guest" />}>
              <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </>
  );
```

##### `index.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

import { createStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import entities from './Redux/config/entities';
import { injectStore } from './Api/nutritivApi';

export const store = createStore(
  entities,
  /* preloadedState, */
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__({
    trace: true
  })
);

injectStore(store);

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been some changes in `React v18` that might cause different behaviors.
[Check this article](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html)

I recommend disabling **StrictMode** , that worked for me .